# How to make work viewport device width?

Tags: css

The image does not increase in 100% width on the mobile device with a resolution of 320px, what's wrong? In the template there is such a tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

The code is

```
    <style type="text/css">

/* For devices with a resolution of 320px */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) { 

     .list .col-sm-4 > a  img {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 180px;
     }   

}


/* Main */
.list .col-sm-4 > a  img {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 160px;
}

    </style>
```

I come from a mobile device, they are used, but not for the screen and (min-width: 320px)

Comment: Change `height: 180px;` to `height: auto;`.

Comment: Place media queries after non-media-query-scoped rulesets.

Comment: Styles for the computer are applied on the mobile phone, a styles for the permission 320px are ignored, why is that?